# How to set Unlimited scrollback for xfce4-terminal?

Tags: scroll, terminal, settings, command-line-interface, xfce

Considering xubuntu 13.04 (based on xfce4.10 distribution), How to set Unlimited scrollback for xfce4-terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

xubuntu 13.04 (based on xfce4.10 distribution) did not yet support unlimited scrolling for xfce4-terminal, How ever, in xfce4-terminal -> edit -> preferences -> Scrollback can be set to max value of 1048576.

Comment: In September 2015, with xfce4-terminal 0.6.3, the max value is 5242880.

Comment: @GreenRaccoon23 `1048576` appears to still be the maximum in 0.6.3

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify AvindraGoolcharan's comment, in newer versions of the xfce4-terminal, unlimited scrollback is possible. For versions 0.8.0 and above, there is a built in option to enable it.

Unfortunately, **all versions of xfce4-terminal >= 0.8.0 require some version of gtk-3.0 (at a minimum, version 3.14), which is not available for 13.04. vte-2.91 is also required, which again is not available for 13.04**.

For those who do have a version of xfce4-terminal that's 0.8.0 or newer,
according to the [XFCE docs](https://docs.xfce.org/apps/terminal/preferences#scrolling), in Edit>Preferences, you check the unlimited scrollback box.

Or as @AvindraGoolcharan suggested, you can append `~/.config/xfce/terminal/terminalrc` with the line `ScrollingUnlimited=TRUE`

I found an example of an xfce4-terminal config file that has the unlimited scrollback option added in GitHub user [eltonvs's dotfiles](https://github.com/eltonvs/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc).

Answer (score 0):

For clarification. xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 settings allows to enter scrollback value 5242880, but the maximum is still set to 1048576.

```
$ grep ScrollingLines ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
ScrollingLines=1048576
```

Comment: I have `0.8.1` and can use the `ScrollingUnlimited=TRUE` setting